# If $G$ acts on $A$ and $A\cong B$, how does $G$ act on $B$?

Tags: representation-theory, solution-verification, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on a vector space $A$. If $T:A\rightarrow B$ is an isomorphism, it seems natural that $G$ should also act on $B$. My guess is that the resulting action $B$ should be defined by 
$$
g.b:= T(g.T^{-1}(b)).
$$
It clearly satisfies $(gh).b=g.h.b$ for any $g,h\in G$. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Possibly it would work even better if you corrected the typo $T^{-1}(b)$ :). Generally you should think of isomorphisms as meaning two objects are just the same thing up to relabeling, so this is indeed the obvious way to let $G$ act on $B$. Your title sounds a bit strange because there are likely other ways that $G$ acts on $B$ - eg via the trivial action.

Comment: Yes this is right. In general this process of turning structure (operations, relations, topology etc.) on a set into structure on another set is called **transport of structure**.